# Why can't I kill a process?

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, task-manager

Thunderbird has crashed and all attempts to kill `thunderbird.exe` are to no avail. I've tried Task Manager and *Process Explorer* from [Sysinternals](http://sysinternals.com) and simply nothing happens when I select 'Kill'.

I try `taskkill`:

```
>taskkill /IM thunderbird.exe /F
SUCCESS: The process "thunderbird.exe" with PID 6404 has been terminated.
```

The output suggests it works, yet `thunderbird.exe` with PID 6404 remains.

A reboot finally shifts it.

There probably isn't much I can do to prevent this happening again, but I'm curious as to, at least in general, what can cause a process to end up such in a state where it cannot be terminated. Does anyone have any ideas on this point?

Comment: In _Process Explorer_ you can select File -> Show Details for All Processes or Run As Administrator which might enable killing of a hung process like this. I've had some success with this method in the past.

Comment: You should try to kill it as administrator ?